# Selector input[name^= doesn't work on change of a select

Tags: jquery

I am having problem catching the on change event of a select.
No problems if the selector points directly to an id. But with,
it doesn't work.
Do you know why?

Here is a chunk of my code:

```
<html>
<head><title></title>

  <link rel=stylesheet href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>


....

  <select name="type_book_1" id="type_book_1">
    <option value="ae">airplane</option>
    <option value="ca">car</option>
   </select>

....
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(document.body).on('change', 'input[name^="type_book"]', function () {
        alert('Change Happened');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your element is a `select`, not an `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the element selector `input` is wrong, it should be `select`

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'select[name^="type_book"]', function () {
    alert('Change Happened');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7gMn2/)

Answer (score 1):

write  `select` at the place of `input`

```
  $(document).on('change','select[name^="type_book"]',function(){
                            // ^^^^here write select at the place of input
                                alert('Change Happened');
                });
```

see **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/S5mnh/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(document.body).on('change', ':input[name^="type_book"]', function () {
    alert('Change Happened');
});
```

Here, the [**`:input`**](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector will select all input, textarea, select and button elements.

But, in your case you are using the `input` selector which only selects the `input` type elements only, not the `select` elements. Hence, your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/nxf6U/)

selector `input` is wrong, change it to `select`

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'select[name^="type_book"]', function () {
    alert('Change Happened');
});
```